# Setting up URL Dots

Tags: php, url, loops, while-loop, hyperlink

The code should allow this to create variable `$Dots`
If the URL was for example:
`http://example.com/1/2`
It will result with a `1` and `$Dots` will contain `../` allowing all links/photos to show up easily. If it was to result in `2` it would return `../../` and so on. Though, it just infinitely loops.

```
<?php
        //Set up URL Dots. Fixes directory issues.
    $ORIGINAL_DOTS = str_ireplace('/test_link','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $COUNT_DOTS = substr_count($ORIGINAL_DOTS,'/')-1;
    $END_DOTS = 0;
    $Dots = '';
    echo $COUNT_DOTS;
    if($COUNT_DOTS != 0){
        while ($END_DOTS <= $COUNT_DOTS){
            if($END_DOTS != $COUNT_DOTS){
                $END_DOTS ++;
                $Dots .= '../';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: ahhh, my eyes! Too many capital letters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your loop will run forever.

```
while ($END_DOTS <= $COUNT_DOTS){
  if($END_DOTS != $COUNT_DOTS){
    $END_DOTS ++;
    $Dots .= '../';
  }
}
```

Consider what will happen when `$END_DOTS == $COUNT_DOTS`. The if-block within the loop won't execute, so the condition `$END_DOTS <= $COUNT_DOTS` will remain true, hence the loop will run forever.

Instead, you should use

```
while ($END_DOTS < $COUNT_DOTS){
  $END_DOTS ++;
  $Dots .= '../';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($END_DOTS <= $COUNT_DOTS){
      if($END_DOTS != $COUNT_DOTS){
           $END_DOTS ++;
           $Dots .= '../';
```

The if statement only executes if $END_DOTS is not equal to $COUNT_DOTS. If they are equal, then your mechanism for escaping the while loop will not run. However, the condition in the while loop is true if $END_DOTS == $COUNT_DOTS, hence your infinite loop. Try doing this:

```
while ($END_DOTS < $COUNT_DOTS){
```

Answer (score 1):

Much more easily written as

```
$ORIGINAL_DOTS = str_ireplace('/test_link', '', 'http://example.com/1/2');
$COUNT_DOTS = substr_count($ORIGINAL_DOTS, '/')-2;
$Dots = str_repeat('../', $COUNT_DOTS);
```